# getting a particular instance on a domain in grails

Tags: grails

I have one gsp file which calls a method like this:

```
<g:link id="${child.id}" action="callChildProfile" controller="profile">${child.firstname}</g:link>
```

which calls this method

```
    def callChildProfile(Long id){

           childInstance = Child.get(id)
           System.out.println(childInstance.firstname + "  child instance")
           redirect(action:  "index")

   }
```

this method set a child instance to a public variable called child instance but when the redirect happens the variable is reset.
The reason I redirect is because I want to load up the index page from this controller.

Index looks like this:

```
        def index() {
        def messages = currentUserTimeline()
        [profileMessages: messages]
         System.out.println(childInstance + " child here")
        [childInstance : childInstance]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in controller methods (actions) have a local scope, thus, only can be used in that method. You should pass the id from new instance and use that id for retrieve the object.

```
redirect action: "index", id: childInstance.id
```

and index could be

```
def index(Long id){
    childInstance = Child.get(id)
```

Then you can conclude that you don't need the callChildProfile method

or you can use params

```
def index(){
    childInstance = Child.get(params.id)
    if(childInstance){
        doSomething()
    }
    else{
        createOrGetOrDoSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Comment: but would that mean every time I called index I would have to give it a long id?

Comment: I wrote an alternative in my answer

Answer (score 2):

By default controllers are prototype scoped, which means the instance of `ProfileController` used will be different between the request which calls `callChildProfile` and the request which calls `index`.  Thus, the object level `childInstance` variable won't be available between requests.

To use the `Child` instance in the `index` call, look at the [chain](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html) method:

```
callChildProfile(Long id){
    // do usual stuff
    chain(action:"index", model:[childInstance:childInstance])
}

def index() {
    // do other stuff
    [otherModelVar:"Some string"]
}
```

When returning a `Map` from `index` the model of the chain call will be automatically added, so your `childInstance` from the `callChildProfile` will be available for the gsp.